# google chart showing wrong graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, google-visualization

hello people below is my code for google chart...

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

  var data = [["00:00:00",60,0.01,0.01],
              ["00:01:00",58,0.01,0.01],
              ["00:02:00",56,0.01,0.01],
              ["00:03:00",55,0,0],
              ["00:04:00",54,0,0],
              ["00:05:00",53,-0.01,-0.01],
              ["00:30:00",53,-0.01,-0.01]];

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

      var temp1 = data[i][0].split(':');

      for(var j=0; j<temp1.length; j++){
          var temp2 = parseInt(temp1[j].replace(/^0/, ''),10);
          temp1[j] = temp2;
      }
      temp1.push(0);
      data[i][0] = temp1;
  }

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('timeofday', 'Period');    
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'SOC');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Control Signal');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Charge/discharge');

  dataTable.addRows(data);


  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
                    title: 'Charge Discharge Management',
                    curveType: 'function',
                    series: {0: {targetAxisIndex:0},
                             1: {targetAxisIndex:1}, 
                            }
                };
  chart.draw(dataView, options);
}
```

In the above code in `data` has almost same values for `Control Signal` and `Charge/discharge` ,,, then why does the graph line is different? `Charge/discharge` yellow line... is plotting from right axis.. how do we make it plot from left axis?? please help me to fix this...

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshwerkushwaha/128sdznL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the yellow series:

```
series: {0: {targetAxisIndex:0},
         1: {targetAxisIndex:1},
         2:{targetAxisIndex:1} // add this
         }
```